# New Game+ vs. Importing again: What will I lose?

Tags: mass-effect-3

I imported my Mass Effect 2 Shepard, which in turn was imported from Mass Effect.

The obvious benefits of starting a New Game+ is that I'll keep my level from the end of Mass Effect 3, but I've been hearing that starting a new game+ with a character that was previously imported, will cause you to lose some of the benefits you got from importing your character.

What exactly will I lose vs what I will gain from starting a new game+

The reason I ask is because levels don't matter so much to me, since by the time I finished ME3 I had all the skills I wanted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You won't lose anything. The ME1 and 2 import data is preserved inside your ME3 save, and carries over with subsequent imports.

Comment: Just did some testing because I was expecting to start out a new game+ with 0 reputation like in ME2, but I started out maxed (also kaiden was alive even though I'm male), so what you're saying seems to be correct.